# SQL Server : return boolean if timestamp is within 1 minute

Tags: sql-server

Disclaimer that I am very novice on SQL writing...

How would I return a single boolean if any record within the query has a timestamp updated within the last 1 minute.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE mytimestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you one row if there is any record matching the criteria:

```
select exists (
  select 1 from mytable where mytimestamp >= dateadd(minute, -1, getdate()) )
```

You could use `current_timestamp` which is ANSI SQL equivalent of `getdate()`.

Comment: Awesome. Is it possible to return that as an additional column to the select statement?

Comment: Yes, it is. You better initialize it as a variable and then add it in your select like any other column, so that it is calculated only once.